# Selenium tests / Java Polymorphism

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

It is a good practice to inherit elements from superclass and use them in subclasses? (elements that are reusable and perform different actions like sendkeys or click)

Comment: Why are you mentioning polymorphism in your question? Looks like you mean the inheritance.. Can you provide the code example?

Comment: I was mentioning polymorphism because I am using those methods/elements to perform different tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it is a good practice to define common methods like `clickVisibleElement()`, `sendTextToElement()`, `scrollElementIntoView()` etc. and common element locators like `saveBtn`, `cancelBtn` etc. in `BasePage` class and use them in the entire project inherited by all the page classes where they can be used.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to POM and good practices in general, one should rely on [composition over inheritance](https://medium.com/@rufuszh90/effective-java-item-16-favour-composition-over-inheritance-ed82e482fd1a). This means all reusable code and object map should reside in its own container/class that you can invoke in your tests or pages, depending on the current design.

For example:

```
public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {           
     this.driver = driver; 
     this.loginForm = new LoginForm(driver);
     // other forms in that page, like SingUp etc.
}
```